# Magento only for virtual products

Tags: magento2, module, virtual-products, virtual

I want to use Magento only for virtual products. I don't want any shipping methods, other product types, wishlist, compare, and all. I'm not sure what are all the core modules I have to disable to make the site faster. Because I'm not going to use all the other things. My flow is below.

- The customer sees virtual products and selects the products.
- Log in using social media.
- Pays money and completes orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Add to compare, Add to wishlist from the backend using stores->configuration. Shipping method is automatically work based on product type. So if our product is virtual or downloadable then shipping method will not display at frontend.